# how to print particular amount corresponding to particular date in php

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have fetched array with following structure:

```
   Array
    (
    [record] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [amount] => 80
                [dates] => 12-Mar-2014
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [amount] => 80
                [dates] => 12-Mar-2015
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [amount] => 140
                [dates] => 13-Mar-2015
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [amount] => 80
                [month_year] => 03-2014
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [amount] => 220
                [month_year] => 03-2015
            )

    )

  )
```

in my view I have to fetch only current day's amount (13-Mar-2015) and current months amount and I don't know how to make condition that if month is current month of current year then print amount corresponding to that month from array and if day is current day of current year then fetch only that amount corresponding to that particular date from array..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use an if condition while inside the loop, include also checking indices for `dates` or `month_year`, something like this:

```
foreach($array['record'] as $record) {
    $dates = date('d-M-Y');
    $month_year = date('m-Y');
    if(
        (isset($record['dates']) && $record['dates'] == $dates) ||
        (isset($record['month_year']) && $record['month_year'] == $month_year)
    ) {
        echo $record['amount'];
    } 
}
```